# Assets not found with sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I started a sails project (with `sails new project --linker`) and everything was working correctly until today.

Now I get a 404 error with all of my javascripts, and I noticed that each time I launch the server (`sails lift`) the `.tmp/public` folder is deleted. I didn't modified the `gruntfile` or any core files and there are no errors displayed on the console.

Answer (score 0):

the `.tmp` folder is deleted every time you issue `sails lift`. This is where sails stores its public dir for the http server.

If i remember correctly, `v0.10` has linker enabled by default.

Try running `sails new project` without the `--linker` and see what shows up in `assets/` there should be a linker folder.

If not, create the folder and add the appropriate tags to your ejs file.

You can see the docs for v0.10 [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.10/assets.md) for more information specificy to a